# Не отсылается письмо через Google SMTP

Tags: modx, openserver, formit

Pаботаю на *OpenServer*.

Не работает этот код, перенаправляет на главную страницу с *url* текста сообщения:

```
[[!FormIt?
&hooks =`email`
&emailTo =`mysitemail@gmail.com`
&redirectTo =`2`
&emailTpl=`testingg`
]]

<form action="[[~[[*id]]]]">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="[[!+fi.name]]" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Что в коде не так?

**Обновление**

```
[[!FormIt?
    &hooks=`email,redirect`
    &emailTo =`mysitemail@gmail.com`
    &emailTpl=`testingg`
    &redirectTo=`2`
]]
```

Добавил редирект, и все-равно не туда отправляет, и не отсылает мейлы  на почту.

**Обновление 2**

Такс, я тут лазил, у узнал о Гугловском SMTP, настроил его в OpenServer. Важно знать, что при включенном SMTP в ModX он не работает (не знаю почему). В общем, теперь отправка идет и приходит. Пока ограничился тем что сам себе пишу. Буду настраивать далее и дорабатывать.

Comment: Думается, что в списке *hooks* забыли указать *redirect*, чтобы redirectTo сработал

Comment: Попробуйте указать также в самой форме `method="post"`